# Insert script by webpack

Tags: webpack

In my desktop electron app I'm generating html pages by webpack like so:

```
  entry: {
    renderer: path.join(__dirname, '../src/renderer/pages/main.js'),
```

...

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: 'index.html',
  chunks: ['renderer'],
  template: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/index.ejs'),
  minify: {
    collapseWhitespace: true,
    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
    removeComments: true
  },
  nodeModules: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
    ? path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules')
    : false
}),
```

However I'm building app to .exe and I don't have access to html post build. Can I somehow configure webpack so whitin `index.html` before `</body>` it would add `<script>console.log('just demo')</script>`?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, is there any problem to add this script into `../src/index.ejs`?

Comment: Yes for some reason it ignores `<script>`s within index.ejs

Comment: Did you try something like that https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template/blob/86f285d5c790a6c15263f5cc50fd666d51f974fd/index.html?